# Paulin 8-12x1-1/4-inch Yellow Plastic Anchors

Tags: drywall-anchor

What does "8-12x1-1/4-inch" mean exactly in "[Paulin 8-12x1-1/4-inch Yellow Plastic Anchors](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/paulin-8-12x1-14-inch-yellow-plastic-anchors--12pc/1000409825?eid=PS_GOOGLE_D00%20-%20E-Comm_GGL_Shopping_PLA_EN_All%20Products_All%20Products__PRODUCT_GROUP_pla-300587868876&gclid=Cj0KCQiAveebBhD_ARIsAFaAvrENYneyo1guo0nqA9w8_9t6xNbNibVTfmVBaF-a5_QFBg1y0-4cBcQaAnWtEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)"? Does "8" mean "[gauge #8](https://handycrowd.com/screws-explained-gauge-size-pilot-holes-and-wall-plugs/)"? I don't know how to interpret the remaining numbers. Please help and thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(#8-12) Indicates that size 8 through size 12 screws can be used in the plugs.
(1 1/4) is indeed the length of the plug. The packaging also recommends a 1/4"  hole be used for the plug to be inserted into.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations!